# Author page doesn't change after username change

Tags: author, permalinks

I changed my user profile name with WP-Optimize from 'admin' to 'indie' (not really 'indie', just to show you better) but author page still is available only trough example.com/author/admin - not example.com/author/indie. Is there anything I missed?

Greetings, .wired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at [**Change the Author Slug from Username to Nickname**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/change-the-author-slug-from-username-to-nickname) more specifically at Jan's answer.

Comment: I am not really sure how his answer should help me... ?

Comment: you changed nickname but not the username, simple as that