# Is It A Good Idea To Change Author Slug (user_nicename field) Directly In MySQL DB?

Tags: permalinks, slug

Searching for a how-to on changing author slug, I found two methods:

1. Change the `user_nicename` field in the MySQL database of your WordPress site to whatever you want the slug to be.
2. [Changing the Author Slug from Username to Nickname](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5742/10691)

The (2) is out of question because I want the slug to be something custom, but not the nickname/nicename.

As for (1) I wanted to know if this is okay -- to change the value of `user_nicename` field in the database for the user?

Comment: I upvoted @Joshua but as confirmation I have done this on sites that I manage and have not had any issues. Mind the caveat's in Joshua's answer though.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Good; that's what I was hoping for. Provide an answer if you have a better solution, or simply upvote the existing one so that I can reward the bounty to it.

Comment: I did upvote the existing answer. If your theme and plugins are written well you shouldn't have much trouble... that is a big "if" with some themes and plugins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Providing you know what you're doing that shouldn't be a problem. You will however have to check that any author/user pages you may have are linked by id rather than name in the code:

```
$data = get_userdata( $userid );
```

As opposed to

```
$data = get_userdata('Admin');
```

Because the ID will never change (unless you delete the row and re-insert) but if you change `Admin` to `Supreme Overlord, Master of this Domain` the second reference will not work but the first will.

NOTE, this will not break the usage of `current_user_can($capability)` but will break `user_can('Admin',$capability)` but I don't see why you would be using `user_can()` over `current_user_can()` anyways.