# How to change the Author Slug from Username to Nickname and deal with Special Characters

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, author, slug

I need to change the author slug from username to nickname:

This is what is set by default: http://domain.tld/author/(username)

This is what I need: http://domain.tld/author/(nickname)-(author-ID)

As I am running a multi-author-blog, I do need a functional fix instead of manually changing the author slug in the database. I tried the following [workaround](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/change-the-author-slug-from-username-to-nickname), but some authors are using special characters (e.g. "&", accent marks or umlauts) in their nickname, which is failing the solution.

Additionally, I need to get a solution for duplicate author nicenames. Maybe its possible to add the author ID to the end of the author slug?