# Disable author admin just use name.

Tags: username

I have a WPMU installation where I am super admin and im developing my blog there for my team. When I click on my name on the post, to show all my post its redirecting me to /blog/author/admin instead of /blog/author/myname.

I never registered a account with the name Admin. Is it possible to just show the name of the user like with all the other not admins.

Comment: is your user registered for that blog?

Comment: yes its the super admin/normal admin.

Comment: Have you seen [Change the Author Slug from Username to Nickname](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5742/22534)