# Author posts url... way to get display name to be url instead of user's ID?

Tags: author

I'm trying to get my authors blog post byline content to link to their archive page of posts. I've got everything working, but would rather the author post link be:

**http://example.com/author/firstname-lastname/** instead of **http://example.com/author/user_id/**

Basically using their display name for the url.

Is that possible?

The current code I have for my byline is:

```
<?php
    printf( __( 'Originally Posted: <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="%1$s" pubdate>%2$s</time> by <span class="author" itemprop="author"><a href="%3$s" title="Posts by %4$s">%4$s</a></span>', 'ea_theme' ),
    get_the_time('Y-m-j'),
    get_the_time(get_option('date_format')),
    get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )),
    get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ) );
?>
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/change-the-author-slug-from-username-to-nickname); the accepted answer might have what you need, or at least get you started in the right direction. Or if you'd prefer a plugin, check out [Edit Author Slug](https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/) (I have no affiliation).

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel! The plugin I posted below works great. And works with 4.1

Answer (score -2):

This plugin does the job nicely: https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-name-author-permalink/