# Change the author slug from nickname to ID

Tags: users, urls, author, slug

I've changed the default registering option by allowing people to sign up with their e-mail addresses. They also have an option to add their firstname, lastname but it's not required.

```
// Allow email instead of nickname for login 
add_filter('authenticate', function($user, $email, $password){

    //Check for empty fields
    if(empty($email) || empty ($password)){        
        //create new error object and add errors to it.
        $error = new WP_Error();
        if(empty($email)){ //No email
            $error->add('empty_username', __('<strong>Viga</strong>: Unustasid sisestada e-posti aadressi'));
        }
        else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //Invalid Email
            $error->add('invalid_username', __('<strong>Viga</strong>: E-posti aadress on vale.'));
        }
        if(empty($password)){ //No password
            $error->add('empty_password', __('<strong>Viga</strong>: Unustasid sisestada parooli'));
        }
        return $error;
    }

    //Check if user exists in WordPress database
    $user = get_user_by('email', $email);

    //bad email
    if(!$user){
        $error = new WP_Error();
        $error->add('invalid', __('<strong>Viga</strong>: E-posti aadress või parool ei ole õige.'));
        return $error;
    }
    else{ //check password
        if(!wp_check_password($password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID)){ //bad password
            $error = new WP_Error();
            $error->add('invalid', __('<strong>Viga</strong>: E-posti aadress või parool ei ole õige.'));
            return $error;
        }else{
            return $user; //passed
        }
    }
}, 20, 3);
```

But this raises a problem. On the author page, users e-mail addresses become public:

```
http://example.com/author/email-address/
```

I know how do change the /author/ part of the URL:

```
add_action('init', 'cng_author_base');
function cng_author_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $author_slug = 'autor'; // change slug name
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
}
```

but not how do change the username to show the ID of the author.
Can it be done?

Comment: A little late, but check out this thread: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/change-the-author-slug-from-username-to-nickname](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/change-the-author-slug-from-username-to-nickname) You would just have to use the ID instead of the nickname...

Answer (score 2):

Surprised to see this unanswered for this long. This is pretty simple to do with a simple block of code:

```
function set_my_nice_name() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $user_table SET `user_nicename`=`ID`");
}
add_action('init', 'set_my_nice_name');
```

This works because the visible portion of an author slug (or profile slug in BuddyPress) uses the `user_nicename` column in the users table and this just copies the user ID to that column for everyone in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Something to have in mind is that authors queries could become really predictable. Adding `+1` isn't that hard. Abuse from bots could arise, retrieving data through puppeteer for example.

We could append to the user ID the `user_registered` by sanitizing it. We would get a nice random-ish string of numbers which would actively prevent bots and users from jumping through pages.

We can catch the user ID upon registration then update `user_nicename` with the required value.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpso208792' );

function wpso208792( $user_id ) {

    $userdata = array (
        'ID' => $user_id, 
        'user_nicename' => sanitize_title_with_dashes( $user_id . str_replace ( array( '-', ' ', ':', ), '', get_userdata( $user_id )->user_registered ) ),
    );

    wp_update_user( $userdata );

};
```

If you're not interested in randomizing the user `user_nicename` just remove  `. str_replace ( array( '-', ' ', ':', ), '', get_userdata( $user_id )->user_registered )` from the value.