# Can't use Persian/Farsi in Author slug (returns 404)

Tags: author, slug

I have modified author links to show nickname instead of username, using [this tutorial](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/change-the-author-slug-from-username-to-nickname).
It works correctly with English names, but when I use Persian, it returns a 404.

What's wrong?
I've also tried "Edit Author Slug" plugin, but it had the same problem; when I entered Persian characters, it gave an error.
Not Saving permalinks nor refreshing didn't help.

Comment: I also prefer to use `display_name` instead of `nickname`.

Comment: Persian characters are not allowed in URI and should be [`urlencoded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: I can use Persian characters anywhere without any problem. This is the first case when I get a 404 error page.

Comment: @MaxYudin I'm very beginner in php. Can you please tell me how can I do this in the urls created with the tutorial mentioned?